# Implementing GUI for Showroom of Vehicles

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, actionlistener

I am having trouble with creating a GUI for a showroom which has vehicle objects contained within it. I'm using a `JFrame` and have got the basic outline with buttons for next, previous and sell on the edges (using Compass Layout). I have added `actionListeners` to each of these but I can't work out how to call the corresponding method in the `Vehicle` or `Showroom` class. Am I supposed to have a main method in the `JFrame` class?

I need to also display the current vehicles details in the center panel but don't understand how I do this?

Here is some of the code:

```
    public class VehicleJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    private JButton previousButton;
    private JButton sellButton;
    private JButton nextButton;
    private JPanel centerPanel;


    public VehicleJFrame()
    {
        super("Vehicle GUI");
        setSize(800, 400);
        setLocation(400, 200);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        createGUI();

        setVisible(true);

    }


    public void createGUI()
    {
        previousButton = new JButton();
        sellButton = new JButton();
        nextButton = new JButton();
        centerPanel = new JPanel();

        //Add code for center panel to display the current vehicle
        previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
        previousButton.addActionListener(this);
        sellButton = new JButton("Sell");
        sellButton.addActionListener(this);
        nextButton = new JButton("Next");
        nextButton.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.RED);
        getContentPane().add(previousButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        getContentPane().add(sellButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        getContentPane().add(nextButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        if (e.getSource() == previousButton)
        {
            //What goes here?
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == sellButton)
        {

        }
        else if (e.getSource() == nextButton)
        {

        }

    }

}


    public class Vehicle
{

    //**********Declarations**********
    private String manufacturer;
    private String model;
    private String customerName = null;
    private String VIN;
    private String dateOfManufacture;
    private String dateOfSale = null;
    private Boolean sold = false;
    private char taxBand;
    private int costOfVehicle;


    //**********Constructor**********
    public Vehicle(String man, String mod, String VIN, String dateOfMan, char taxBand, int costOfVehicle)
    {
        this.manufacturer = man;
        this.model = mod;
        this.VIN = VIN;
        this.dateOfManufacture = dateOfMan;
        this.taxBand = taxBand;
        this.costOfVehicle = costOfVehicle;
    }


    //**********toString() method for Vehicle information**********
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Vehicle\n{\n" + " manufacturer = " + manufacturer
                + "\n model = " + model
                + "\n customerName = " + customerName
                + "\n VIN = " + VIN
                + "\n dateOfManufacture = " + dateOfManufacture
                + "\n dateOfSale = " + dateOfSale
                + "\n sold = " + sold
                + "\n taxBand = " + taxBand
                + "\n CO2 Emmissions = " + getCO2Group()
                + "\n costOfVehicle = " + costOfVehicle + "\n" + '}';
    }


    public String buyVehicle(String customerName, String dateOfSale)
    {
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.dateOfSale = dateOfSale;
        sold = true;

        return sold.toString();
    }


    public class Showroom
{

    private ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleArrayList;
    private String showroomName;
    private int currentPos;


    public Showroom(String name)
    {
        showroomName = name;
        vehicleArrayList = new ArrayList();
        currentPos = 0;
    }


    public boolean addVehicle(Vehicle newVehicle)
    {
        vehicleArrayList.add(currentPos, newVehicle);

        return true;
    }
    public Vehicle getCurrentVehicle()
    {
        return vehicleArrayList.get(currentPos);
    }


    public boolean next()
    {
        if (vehicleArrayList.size() - 1 > currentPos)
        {
            currentPos++;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public boolean previous()
    {
        if (currentPos > 0)
        {
            currentPos--;
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you should have a main method in the VehicleFrame class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used a JOptionPane and some slight alterations to demonstrate a way you could display your data in the frame.  I have added a JTextPane for displaying the data, and a way for adding cars via a button in the GUI you have made.  To go on from here I would suggest using previous and next buttons to iterate over the arrayList of cars you have in the showroom after adding more cars to begin with.
Have a look and see what if it helps:

```
    public class VehicleJFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

private JButton previousButton;
private JButton addButton; //NEW - For adding vehicles
private JButton sellButton;
private JButton nextButton;
private JPanel centerPanel;
private JTextPane displayPane;
private Showroom theShowRoom;


public VehicleJFrame()
{
    super("Vehicle GUI");
    setSize(800, 400);
    setLocation(400, 200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    createGUI();

    setVisible(true);

}


public void createGUI()
{
    previousButton = new JButton();
    sellButton = new JButton();
    nextButton = new JButton();
    centerPanel = new JPanel();

    //Add code for center panel to display the current vehicle
    previousButton = new JButton("Previous");
    previousButton.addActionListener(this);
    sellButton = new JButton("Sell");
    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    sellButton.addActionListener(this);
    nextButton = new JButton("Next    ");
    nextButton.addActionListener(this);
    addButton.addActionListener(this);
    displayPane = new JTextPane();//NEW - For displaying
    displayPane.setEditable(false);//NEW - Only for display so no editing
    theShowRoom = new Showroom("Showroom 1");//NEW - To store our vehicles in

    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
    getContentPane().add(displayPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);//NEW - The place to display cars in the middle
    getContentPane().add(previousButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    getContentPane().add(sellButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    getContentPane().add(addButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);//NEW - The add button
    getContentPane().add(nextButton, BorderLayout.EAST);

}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{

    if (e.getSource() == previousButton)
    {

    }
    else if (e.getSource() == sellButton)
    {

    }
    else if (e.getSource() == nextButton)
    {

    }
    else if (e.getSource() == addButton){
        Vehicle v = new Vehicle(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Manafacturer"),
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Model"),
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Vin"),
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Manafacture date"),
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Tax band").charAt(0),
                Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "cost")));
        theShowRoom.addVehicle(v);//Add to showroom
        displayPane.setText(theShowRoom.getCurrentVehicle().toString());
      }



}

public static void main(String[] args){ //To test the program
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        new VehicleJFrame();

    }
});
}}
```

I have added a main method so you should be able to just run this with your other classes.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your main should look like this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            new VehicleJFrame();
        }
    }):
}
```

Note: You should invoke your JFrame like this as they are not thread safe